# How to make VSCode indent correctly when pressing enter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, indentation

I just started using VSCode to program in C/C++.

Sometimes (e.g. after deleting a line break) I am in the following situation, where `|` represents the cursor:

```
    x = 5;|    y = 10;
```

If I press enter, then it becomes

```
    x = 5;
    |    y = 10;
```

but I want the line `y = 10;` to be automatically indented to the correct place, namely

```
    x = 5;
    y = 10;
```

This is the expected behavior in Visual Studio, which I can't get in VSCode.

In the setting, `Editor: Auto Indent` is set to `full`. I also enabled `Editor: Format On Type`, if that matters.

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: what if you set the indent to `smart`

Comment: @rioV8 Do you mean the setting in `Editor: Auto Indent`? I don't see a `smart` option though. Those I have are: `none`, `keep`, `brackets`, `advanced`, `full`. I have tried all these and none worked.

Comment: I think I remember there was an indent related setting that had the `smart` option, but I can't find it anymore

Comment: @WhatsUp you solve it?

Comment: @PandaSoli Unfortunately no. Whenever possible, I use Visual Studio Community Edition to write C/C++ codes.